# How to delete win8 and reinstall win 7 from disc

Tags: windows-8

I wish to delete Windows 8 and go back to Windows 7, which was originally installed. Having done the compatibility check for a Windows 7 installation it did not throw up a problem. However, on trying to install I got message error 0x0. I am happy to format the hard drive if that is what is needed.

Comment: Was that the complete error message? Where did you get that error - right at the start when you attempted to boot from the Win7 DVD?

Comment: Also, please explain exactly how you are attempting to install. With a new CD? With an ISO you have downloaded? With a USB stick? Are you trying to install from _within_ Win8 or are you booting from a CD/USB?

Answer (score 1):

One of my Win7 installs was similar but not exactly like yours, but I recall the option within the Windows 7 dvd installer to edit and/or format the partition(s) on the hard drive. This would be my suggestion based on what you're saying. There are "Live CD" options based on linux that include hard disk tools, not sure what your familiarity is with all that.